# Simple way to replace value in array in PHP when you know the index

Tags: php, arrays, string, replace

I have created an array in PHP of strings. While my understanding of PHP is imperfect, I believe that arrays are by default ordered by an index and I should be able to access an element of the array using: array[0] or array[1] etc. Regardless, I have created the array by explicitly creating an index with the following code employing a loop:

```
//create empty array container
    $myarray = "";
//create counter
    $i = 0;
//begin loop of limited size...
    $myarray[$i] = "some color...this changes with each iteration of loop";
    $i = $i + 1;
    //end loop
```

Note I end up with something like 1=>red,2+>blue,3+>green etc.

I know this code works because it creates an array that if I implode, gives me the string that I want e.g. redbluegreen

```
$arrayasstring = implode("",$myarray);//produces redbluegreen
```

However, I would like to access one of the values of the loop using the index and change it. For example, I might want to change $array[0] from red to purple.

```
 $index = 0;
    $myarray[$index] = "purple"; //does not work
```

What is a simple way to accomplish this?

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: That should work. What's the difference from your original code in the loop?

Comment: `$myarray = "";` creates a string, not an array.

Comment: Your loop is modifying `$myarray`, but then you use `$array` in the call to `implode()`.

Comment: All these snippets with different variables are confusing, it's hard to tell what you're doing wrong. Please post a [mcve].

Comment: I corrected the myarray vs. array conflict which was a typo.

Comment: That's not enough. Please show the whole code that's causing the problem. You're creating an empty string when you claim to be creating an empty array.

Comment: Your first code block couldn't possible work, because `$myarray` is a string, and the second argument to `implode()` has to be an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To initialize an Array you have to use [] or the function array:

In your example:

```
$myarray = array();
```

If you want to add a series of values with the default key assignment you only have to put in between the parenthesis: array(color1, color2, color3)

```
$myarray = array('blue', 'red', 'yellow')
```

Then you can view what is on your variable, using: print_r($myarray)

```
print_r($myarray)
// this will output:
Array
(
    [0] => blue
    [1] => red
    [2] => yellow
)
```

After this, now you can change the key => value, as you want:

```
$index = 0;
$myarray[$index] = "purple";
print_r($myarray);

//this will now output:
Array
(
    [0] => purple
    [1] => red
    [2] => yellow
)
```

And your job is done.

Observations:

- In your question, you are using two differents arrays: **$myarray** and **$array**, you are having an error because **$array[$index]** is different to the first **$myarray[$i] = "some color...this changes with each iteration of loop";**
- Use print_r($yourVariable) to show what is in the variable to debug what you are doing wrong.

Comment: Not initializing array properly may have been the main issue. Also I was using var_dump which just shows string and number of characters instead of print_r. Using print_r helped me to debug.

Comment: Using $myarray = array('blue', 'red', 'yellow'); you don't need to initialize the array, since you are creating it with values. There's another way that you can initialize it: 
$myArray = []; 
$myArray = array();
$myArray = (array) null;